# How to solve error "export 'MaskDirective' (imported as 'i8') was not found in ngx-mask"?

Tags: node.js, angular, ngx-mask

While building the angular elements getting an error related to ngx-mask. But on library it is working fine.

I am using *node: 18.18.3, ngx-mask: 13.1.15, angular: 13.3.12*.

**error information:**

> Error: export 'NgxMaskDirective' (imported as 'i8') was not found in 'ngx-mask' (possible exports: INITIAL_CONFIG, MaskApplierService, MaskDirective, MaskPipe, MaskService, NEW_CONFIG, NgxMaskModule,
> _configFactory, config, initialConfig, timeMasks, withoutValidation)`

Using node16 build success but node18 not.